# Wordpress Blog URL and Events URL Repeats domain

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, url

For some reason on wordpress, the Urls to events and blog posts are showing up like this:

```
Blog Post URL: http://blackbayarea.co/blog/blackbayarea.co/families-of-orlando-shooting-victims-file-federal-lawsuit-against-tech-companies/

Event URL: http://blackbayarea.co/calendar/blackbayarea.co/event/37th-mlk-jr-luncheon/?instance_id=5845
```

Rather than this:

```
Blog Post URL (Correct): http://blackbayarea.co/families-of-orlando-shooting-victims-file-federal-lawsuit-against-tech-companies/

Event URL (Correct): http://blackbayarea.co/event/37th-mlk-jr-luncheon/?instance_id=5845
```

I would greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Is this a new install of word press or did this just start to happen?

Comment: @chop62 relatively new install of wordpress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your WordPress HOME and SITEURL constants may not be set correctly. Try adding the following in your site's wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://blackbayarea.co');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://blackbayarea.co');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please show the code for that part of the template..

My guess is that you haven't included the protocol part to the link,eg:

```
<a href="example.com/some_link">Some Link</a>
```

would create http://example.com/example.com/some_link

You need to link like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/some_link">Some Link</a>
```